# Lambda capturing constexpr object

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, constexpr

GCC 4.7.2 compiles this:

```
constexpr int i = 5;
[]{ std::integral_constant< int, i >(); }; // nonstandard: i not captured
```

but not this:

```
constexpr int i = 5;
[&i]{ std::integral_constant< int, i >(); }; // GCC says i not constexpr
```

The latter example appears correct to me, according to C++11 §5.1.2/15:

> An entity is captured by reference if it is implicitly or explicitly captured but not captured by copy. It is unspecified whether additional unnamed non-static data members are declared in the closure type for entities captured by reference.

It seems the captured object `i` inside the lambda refers to the variable in the enclosing scope, which is `constexpr`, not merely a `const` reference.

The standard explicitly says that the use of a by-value capture is transformed into a use of the corresponding member of the lambda object. And I think that 5.1.2 hints that my interpretation is correct.

Is there anything that explicitly says that whether a capture by reference refers to the object in the enclosing scope or a reference?

Comment: What happens if you use clang?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Clang compiles both cases.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The second *template-argument* to `std::integral_constant< int, i >` is for a *template-parameter* of *non-type* form, specifically of *integral or enumeration type* (14.3.2p1 bullet 1) and so must be a converted constant expression of type `int`.

In a *lambda-expression*, implicit capture occurs when an entity is odr-used in the compound statement (5.1.2p11); use of a converted constant expression in an explicit template instantiation is not odr-use (3.2p3), so the first example is valid.

In the second example, I think gcc is incorrect to reject it; 5.1.2p17 says in a note that:

> An *id-expression* that is not an odr-use refers to the original entity, never to a member of the closure type.

Although the paragraph as a whole is discussing capture by copy, there's no reason not to apply this rule to capture by reference as well.  It's unsurprising that the standard is unclear on this; there's really no reason to capture an entity that can be used in a converted constant expression by reference.

Comment: Hmm, I was thinking gcc might be correct in rejecting the second example. From 5.1.2p12: `An entity captured by a lambda-expression
is odr-used (3.2) in the scope containing the lambda-expression.` I read that as meaning the explicit capture, i.e. `[&i]` means it is odr-used. I could be wrong though.

Comment: @JesseGood that's saying that `i` is odr-used in the *enclosing* scope, not in the compound statement.

Comment: Yes, perhaps you are right. I guess explicit capture does not warrant odr-use in the lambda expression. Although that area could be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

First, I can confirm your observation with gcc 4.6.3 and clang 3.0 on Ubuntu 12.04.

I don't have the C++11 standard (only draft), so I cannot comment on that. But look at the, from my understanding, equivalent statements

```
constexpr int i = 5;
const int &j = i;
std::integral_constant<int, j>();
```

Neither gcc, nor clang compiles this, because `j` is not an "integral constant".

Comment: Drafts are released regularly; effectively they fix errata in the standard as the committee is still "fixing bugs" not "adding features." The latest is N3485. The point of the question is to ask whether a declaration such as `j` is guaranteed not to be introduced.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Thanks for this info. Then I must "update" my N3242 draft.