# Using lambda captured constexpr value as an array dimension

Tags: arrays, c++11, lambda, c++14, constexpr

`GCC` and `Clang` do compile the following code:

```
void Test()
{
   constexpr int Size = 3;
   auto Lambda = [Size]{ int Dim[Size]; };
}
```

However, `VisualStudio 2015 CTP 6` does not. Nevertheless, all 3 compilers are happy with this code:

```
void Test()
{
   static constexpr int Size = 3;
   auto Lambda = []{ int Dim[Size]; };
}
```

Which snippet is actually doing it in the correct way? What does the C++ standard say?

This question is related to [Lambda capturing constexpr object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13468989/1065190)

Comment: Does VS2015 accept `[&]{ int Dim[Size]; }`?

Comment: @dyo: nope, ``error C2057: expected constant expression``.

Comment: Does VS2015 accept `[]{ int Dim[Size]; }` when `Size` is not `static`?

Comment: @dyp: of course not, ``error C3493: 'Size' cannot be implicitly captured because no default capture mode has been specified``

Comment: It is not obvious that it doesn't accept it: clang++ does.

Comment: @dyp: holy guacamole!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++11 [expr.prim.lambda]/12

> If a lambda-expression odr-uses this or a variable with automatic storage duration from its reaching scope, that entity shall be captured by the lambda-expression.

and /17

> Every *id-expression* that is an odr-use of an entity captured by copy is transformed into an access to the corresponding unnamed data member of the closure type. [ *Note:* An *id-expression* that is not an odr-use
>   refers to the original entity, never to a member of the closure type. [...] 
>    — *end note* ]

So we don't even need to capture `Size` in the first example (where it is not `static`), since reading from that variable is not an odr-use since it can appear in a constant expression and the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is immediately applied to it, [basic.def.odr]/2

> A variable whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression is odr-used unless it is an object that satisfies the requirements for appearing in a constant expression and the lvalue-to-rvalue
>   conversion is immediately applied.

(It is not clear to me if the array bounds require an l-t-r conversion, though.)

The same applies when capturing `Size` by reference, or when capturing `Size` explicitly (by copy) but not odr-using it: the use of the *id-expression* `Size` within the lambda accesses the `constexpr` variable declared in `Test`, not any captured member (for capture-by-copy: IFF the access does not constitute an odr-use).

C++14 [expr.prim.lamda]/12 adds some wording for polymorphic lambdas that is irrelevant here, and moves /17 to /18. The rules for odr-use are more complicated, but I'd argue it's not an odr-use for the same underlying reason (reading a compile-time constant).

Comment: Long story short. Is there a bug in VS 2015?

Comment: @SergeyK. I guess so. I'll try to look up the recent rules (C++14 and post-C++14) which will probably be a bit different. But I can't imagine them being more restrictive here.