# Can I use a constexpr value in a lambda without capturing it?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, constexpr

I would want to use a constexpr value in a lambda. Reading the answer to
*[Using lambda captured constexpr value as an array dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28763375/1065190)*, I assumed the following should work:

```
  #include<array>
  int main()
  { 
    constexpr int i = 0;
    auto f = []{  
      std::array<int, i> a;
    };
    return 0;
  }
```

However, Clang 3.8 (with std=c++14) complains that

> variable 'i' cannot be implicitly captured in a lambda with no
>   capture-default specified

Should this be considered a bug in clang 3.8?

BTW:

The above code does compile with gcc 4.9.2.
If I change the lambda expresion to capture explicitly:

```
...
auto f = [i]{
...
```

clang 3.8 compiles it, but gcc 4.9.2 fails:

> error: the value of ‘i’ is not usable in a constant expression
>   ...

Comment: does `[constexpr int _i =i]{}` does any difference?

Comment: Nope, that does not compile under gcc 4.9.2, nor Clang 3.8.

Comment: hmmm.... I supposed you thought about #define as a (temprary) solution?

Comment: but macros are evil! And plus, they can't be assigned with constexpr function.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot: That's just a mantra. quoting from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041453/why-are-preprocessor-macros-evil-and-what-are-the-alternatives "Macros are just like any other tool - a hammer used in a murder is not evil because it's a hammer. It is evil in the way the person uses it in that way. If you want to hammer in nails, a hammer is a perfect tool."

Comment: Capturing all by value `[=]` or reference `[&]` works for me under gcc 4.9.0 and clang 3.7.

Comment: Indeed the capturing all by value [=] or reference [&] also compiles with gcc 4.9.2 and clang 3.8 (experimental btw). Another work-around as pointed in http://stackoverflow.com/q/28763375/1065190 is using a static constexpr.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Should this be considered a bug in clang 3.8?

Yep. A capture is only needed if [expr.prim.lambda]/12 mandates so:

[image]

Note in particular the highlighted example. `f(x)` does not necessitate `x` to be captured, because it isn't odr-used (overload resolution selects the overload with the object parameter). The same argumentation applies to your code - [basic.def.odr]/3:

> A variable `x` whose name appears as a *potentially-evaluated* expression
>   `ex` is odr-used by `ex` **unless applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion
>   (4.1) to `x` yields a constant expression (5.20) that does not invoke
>   any non-trivial functions…**

This requirement is certainly met.

> **…and, if `x` is an object, `ex` is an element of
>   the set of potential results of an expression `e`, where either the
>   lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) is applied to `e`**, or `e` is a
>   discarded-value expression (Clause 5).

`i` is its set of potential results as per [basic.def.odr]/(2.1), and the l-t-r conversion is indeed immediately applied as its passed to a non-type template parameter of object type.

Hence, as we have shown that (12.1) isn't applicable - and (12.2) clearly isn't, either - Clang is wrong in rejecting your snippet.

Comment: The standard doesn't seem to spend much words on uses of constexpr in lambdas... The code in the example just deals with runtime uses (right?), and compiles fine in both clang 3.8 and g++ 4.9.2.

Comment: Anyways, it indeed does seem wrong in clang. I filed bug https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=25627 .

Comment: @OlafBooij The point is that it can't be a runtime (=odr-) use, since the variable isn't captured. The fact that it compiles is.. self-explanatory, since it's intended to and the devs may even have tested stuff with that exact example.

Comment: Alas, MSVC, a full decade after C++11, still has no compiler that implements this correctly; MSVC insists on `i` being explicitly captured.

Comment: Yes, I'm surprised we need to go so far into the details of the standard to establish this. A 'constexpr' entity `K` is constant at compile time, so binding its value would be redundant, since all instances would bind the same value. If the use of `K` in the lambda requires the address of `K`, then it will be the same address in all instances of the lambda (and the same as for code accessing `K` outside the lambda), so likewise binding by reference would be redundant.

Comment: Seems MSVC may be more inclined to accept it if you add (redundant) `static` to the `constexpr` variable declaration. Maybe works onl older Clang. (Also - if it's something that needs binding, according to some compilers, and I add a binding, to make them happy, why would I then be allowed to use it (as in the example) as a template parameter inside the lambda on any compiler? The second error in OP actually makes sense for that reason).