# lambdas in Clang and MSVC require to capture object not ODR-used

Tags: c++, lambda, one-definition-rule

In the following code:

```cpp
int main(){
  constexpr int a = 123;
  []() {
    int v = (a,123);
    };
}
```

Obviously, this code doesn't require `a` to be *potentially-evaluated* for it's `constexpr`, so it's not ODR-used. Thus it should't require capture of any form.

However, only GCC succeeded to compile this snippet.

Is this a bug existing both in MSVC and clang? Or did I miss something? Whose fault is it?

Comment: the downvoter may give me a reason?

Comment: [..or may not.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285777/4117728)

Comment: (not the down voter) `a` is a [*discarded-value expression*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.prop#def:discarded-value_expression).  AFAIK, that requires the object to be defined, but I'm not sure enough for an answer.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I understand that... I'm just simply requesting him or her to give me a reason to improve my question, or I will be very puzzled. I'm not blaming.

Comment: Actually, looks like I'm wrong.  related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33873788/how-can-i-use-a-constexpr-value-in-a-lambda

Comment: @JohnDing I know your situation very well and my first reflex is often the very same, though experience tells that what you want is constructive critisism and if a user decided to vote instead of leave a comment with constructive critisism then asking to explain the vote is futile. Users that want to leave a constructive comment usually do so

Comment: @NathanOliver Ahh, it's strange that a bug detected 4 years ago is still not fixed now. Feel free to close this qustion, because it's almost identical with that one, except that it's very hard to find that question, for the title is so confusing...

Comment: Yeah, for me to find it I used *can capture constexpr variable without default capture in lambda gcc* as my search query.  I've now changed  the old Q's title to *Can I use a constexpr value in a lambda without capturing it?*

Comment: *" its value is discarded, so it's not ODR-used"*. It seems wrong, change to `(&a, 123)` and then gcc requires the capture.

Comment: @Jarod42 They are completely different behaviors. Operator `&` requires Odr-use on its oprand.

Comment: I meant, it is not because expression is discarded, that `a` should not be captured. if you change to `int v = a;`, most compiler compiles [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/AYv_QZ).

Comment: @Jarod42 I unserstood what you mean, I'll edit my post, thanks. I've seen in cppreferece that only the second parameter is added in to the set of *potentially-evaluation*. But I'm not sure whether the *value-discarded expression* `a` is an ODR-use or not... Anyway, retrieving value from a compile-time constant is not ODR-use, of course, which I didn't notice