# Why can't a constexpr "variable" be seen only by a capturing lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11

Why can't a constexpr "variable" be seen only by a capturing lambda ? For me the a constexpr "variable" should have the same meaning as a static const "variable"; and the latter one can be seen inside a lambda without any capturing.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33873788/can-i-use-a-constexpr-value-in-a-lambda-without-capturing-it would answer your question ?

Answer (score 1):

As the already linked answer is pretty old, I take the example code [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33873788/can-i-use-a-constexpr-value-in-a-lambda-without-capturing-it) and it compiles now fine with clang, gcc. MSVC still rejects the code, however. Seems to be a compiler bug.

```
#include<array>
int main()
{
    constexpr int i = 0; 
    auto f = []{
        std::array<int, i> a;
    };   
    return 0;
}
```

[see on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Yjbxjrhc9)

That gcc and clang is right can be read [lambda capture](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) here:

> **captures**:
> A lambda expression can read the value of a variable without capturing it if the variable :
>
> - is constexpr and has no mutable members.