# GCC and Clang disagree about C++17 constexpr lambda captures

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17

Consider this example which declares a variable as constexpr, captures it by copy in a lambda, and declares another constexpr variable which is the result of a constexpr function unwrapping a non-type template parameter from the original variable.

```
#include <utility>

template<int I>
constexpr auto unwrap(std::integral_constant<int, I>) {
  return I;
}

int main() {
  constexpr auto i = std::integral_constant<int, 42>{};
  constexpr auto l = [i]() {
    constexpr int x = unwrap(i);
  };
}
```

Clang (trunk) accepts this code. ([wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2H7zezNFXdQdyaBz))

GCC (trunk) fails with the following error message ([wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oB7VEymVTfDQuxYG)):

```
lambda_capture.cpp:11:31: error: the value of ‘i’ is not usable in a constant expression
     constexpr int x = unwrap(i);
                               ^
lambda_capture.cpp:10:28: note: ‘i’ was not declared ‘constexpr’
   constexpr auto l = [i]() {
```

Which compiler is correct? It seems to me that this is a GCC bug, where the constexpr-ness of lambda captures is not correctly propagated to the lambda context.

Comment: Considering that C++17 is not a thing yet I wouldn't say that any of them is right or wrong.

Comment: Agree with @freakish, compilers might be reasonably hesitant to implement anything that isn't set in concrete yet.

Comment: The C++17 standard draft is in the [final stages of standardization](https://isocpp.org/std/status) and GCC and Clang both claim to be [language-feature complete](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support). Although it's early, I think it's reasonable to ask questions about how compilers implement the new standard, and it's helpful for the compiler developers to discuss how things should eventually work.

Comment: I know [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468989/lambda-capturing-constexpr-object) is not about c++17 but may be helpful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both implementations are bugged, but I'm inclined to think that GCC got the right answer here.

---

Dropping the capture of `i` causes Clang to refuse to compile the code. That means it clearly has a bug somewhere.

[[expr.const]/2.12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.const#2.12):

> An expression `e` is a core constant expression unless the evaluation
>   of `e`, following the rules of the abstract machine, would evaluate
>   one of the following expressions:
>
> - [...]
> - in a *lambda-expression*, a reference to [...] a variable with automatic storage duration defined outside that *lambda-expression*,
>     where the reference would be an odr-use;
> - [...]

Clang's behavior is schizophrenic: if the use of `i` in the body is not an odr-use, then it doesn't need to be captured, yet it rejects the code in the OP if the explicit capture is removed; OTOH, if it is an odr-use, then by the above `unwrap(i)` isn't a constant expression, and so it should reject the initialization of `x`.

---

GCC's lambda implementation is woefully bad with respect to odr-use. It does constant-folding ultra-early, resulting in all kinds of subtle mischief. On the other hand, for explicit captures it transforms all uses, whether or not it's actually an odr-use. The aggressive constant folding means that it accepts OP's code if the capture of `i` is removed.

Assuming that `unwrap(i)` does odr-use `i`, then it is correct that, per [expr.const]/2.12, OP's code is ill-formed.

---

Does `unwrap(i)` actually odr-use `i`? That question [boils down](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.def.odr#3.sentence-1) to whether copy-initializing the parameter object of `unwrap` counts as applying an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to `i`. I don't see anything in the standard that explicitly says that an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied here, and instead [[dcl.init]/17.6.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#17.6.2) indicates that we call a constructor (in this case, the trivial implicitly defined copy constructor) passing `i` as the argument bound to its parameter, and reference binding is a classic example of odr-use.

To be sure, applying an l-to-r conversion would result in a copy-initialization of an `integral_constant<int, 42>` object from `i`, but the problem here is that nothing in the standard says the converse - that all copy-initializations of an `integral_constant<int, 42>` object from `i` count as l-to-r conversions.

Comment: So you're saying that even if the implicit copy constructor is constexpr, it still counts as an odr-use of `i` and the closure type is a core constant expression. This is frustrating, especially since it sounds like GCC's acceptable of `i` without a capture is also a defect, because I would like to be able to use constexpr variables defined outside of the lambda in a constexpr lambda. Do you think the wording in the standard is inconsistent, or do you think there's a reason it's written this way?

Comment: It seems that removal of the capture reverses behaviour of both compilers.

Comment: Are there bug reports for these?