# constexpr function with unused reference argument – gcc vs clang

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++17, constexpr

Consider the following code:

```
template <int N, typename T> void f(T) { }

template <typename T> 
constexpr int k(T&) { return 0; }

int main() 
{
    constexpr auto i = 1;
    f<k(i)>([&i]
    {
         f<k(i)>(0); 
    });
}
```

`clang++` *(trunk)* compiles it. `g++` *(trunk)* fails with the following error:

> ```
> <source>: In lambda function:
>
> <source>:11:19: error: no matching function for call to 'f<k<const int>((* & i))>(int)'
> 11  |          f<k(i)>(0);
>     |                   ^
>
> <source>:1:35: note: candidate: 'template<int N, class T> void f(T)'
>     1 | template <int N, typename T> void f(T) { }
>       |                                   ^
>
> <source>:1:35: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>
> <source>:11:19: error: '__closure' is not a constant expression
> 11  |          f<k(i)>(0);
>     |                   ^
>
> <source>:11:13: note: in template argument for type 'int'
> 11  |          f<k(i)>(0);
>     |            ~^~~
> ```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://godbolt.org/z/Cdp_ce)

---

Changing `k(T&)` to `k(T)` solves the issue. It seems to me that the problem is related to the fact that the reference argument is not a *constant expression*, but it not used as part of `k`.

**What compiler is correct here?**

Comment: Related: [GCC and Clang disagree about C++17 constexpr lambda captures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44386415/gcc-and-clang-disagree-about-c17-constexpr-lambda-captures). T.C.'s answer also answers your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GCC is correct here.

According to [[expr.const]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.const#4.12):

> An expression `e` is a core constant expression unless the evaluation
>   of `e`, following the rules of the abstract machine, would evaluate
>   one of the following expressions:
>
> - ...
> - in a *lambda-expression*, a reference to [...] a variable with automatic storage duration defined outside that *lambda-expression*,
>     where the reference would be an odr-use; ...
> - ...

`k(i)` odr-uses `i` thus `k(i)` is not a constant expression in the lambda expression, so  this code is ill-formed.

Answer (score 0):

The error is emitted for the expression `k(i)` that appears within the lambda expression compound statements but not outside it. This is a GCC bug. According to [[expr.prim.lambda.capture]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.prim.lambda.capture#11)

> An *id-expression* within the compound-statement of a lambda-expression that is an odr-use of a reference captured by reference *refers to the entity to which the captured reference is bound* and not to the captured reference.

So `k(i)` outside the lambda is the same expression as `k(i)` outside the lambda, so there is no reason for GCC to emit an error for the second expression but not for the first.

Answer (score -1):

Compiled with 0 errors on godbolt.

I used a variable `result_k = k(i);` for bypass this errors.

```
template <int N, typename T> void f(T) { }

template <typename T> constexpr int k(T&) { return 0; }

int main() {
    constexpr auto i = 1;
    const int result_k=k(i);
    f<result_k>([&i]{ f<result_k>(0);});
}
```

Comment: This question is asking which compiler is correct, rather than how to resolve the issue.

Comment: clang++ (trunk) compiles it. g++ (trunk) fails with the following error:

I posted the code beacause the owner use two compilers.. clang and g++, this code work with clag++ and g++

Comment: And yes, that is a answer, but not the one the OP wants to know. This is question is tagged `language-laywer` and OP asks which compiler is correct, not how to fix it. An good answer would be telling OP whether clang or gcc is right, which yours does not do.