# g++ and clang++ different behaviour with lambda capturing `std::integral_constant` by reference

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, constexpr, type-traits

Given the following code

```
#include <type_traits>

int main ()
 {
   std::integral_constant<int, 42> ic;

   [&]{ constexpr int i = ic; (void)i; }();
 }
```

(the `(void)i;` is just to avoid a "unused variable" warning) clang++ compile without problem where g++ gives the following error

```
prog.cc: In lambda function:
prog.cc:7:27: error: '__closure' is not a constant expression
    7 |    [&]{ constexpr int i = ic; (void)i; }();
      |                           ^~
```

Capturing by value

```
[=]{ constexpr int i = ic; (void)i; }();
```

both compilers compile without problem.

The question, as usual, is: who's right? g++ or clang++?

**-- EDIT --**

As pointed by JVApen, `ic` isn't defined `constexpr`; so how can a not-constexpr variable initialize a `constexpr` variable?

Anyway, the behavior doesn't change defining `ic` as `constexpr`

```
constexpr std::integral_constant<int, 42> ic;
```

clang++ compile without problem; g++ gives an error capturing by reference.

**-- EDIT --**

As pointed by Jans, defining `ic` as `constexpr` and using aggregate initialization

```
constexpr std::integral_constant<int, 42> ic{};
```

both compilers compile without problem.

But without `constexpr`

```
std::integral_constant<int, 42> ic{};
```

g++ gives the usual error.

Comment: I actually would think both are wrong, you never define `ic` as a constexpr, so how can you use it to initialize another `constexpr`?

Comment: @JVApen - yes, this is another point that confuse me; anyway, we have the same behaviour also defining `ic` as `constexpr`.

Comment: @JVApen, The value is contained in the type. Even for a non-constexpr variable, the conversion is purely dependent on the type.

Comment: @max66 it does compile if you aggregate initialize `constexpr std::integral_constant<int, 42> ic{}` [here](https://godbolt.org/z/j4J06U)

Comment: @Jans - interesting; thanks. Added your observation to the question.

Comment: I believe g++ is correct here. Formally, `int i = ic` invokes ic's `operator int()` which is a non-static member, which will reference the closure's stored member's `this` even if it's not needed. note that looking up the value via the static member works: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/SZqUIL

Comment: In other words, your example is the same a [this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ZjJZ0P), which seems reasonable to fail.

Comment: @Frank: I don’t think it’s obvious that “referencing” a non-`constexpr` `this` is forbidden: the usual “can’t use a non-constant” is about [lvalue-to-rvalue conversion](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#4.7).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53978006/5376789, https://stackoverflow.com/q/44386415/5376789.