# comma operator makes lambda expression non-constexpr

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, c++17, constexpr

According to [[this Q&A]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27324573/why-was-the-restriction-on-the-comma-operator-being-in-a-constant-expression-rem) since c++11 comma operator is constexpr capable. According to [[this Q&A]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468989/lambda-capturing-constexpr-object) constexpr variable should not be captured by lambda but should be usable inside its body.

Both these rules make following code compilable in clang:

```
//Example 1

template <int>
struct Foo {};

int main() {
    constexpr int c = 1;
    static_cast<void>(Foo<(c, 2)>{});
}
```

---

```
//Example 2

template <int>
struct Foo {};

int main() {
    constexpr int c = 1;
    auto lambda = []{return c * 2;};
    static_cast<void>(Foo<lambda()>{});
}
```

However while both these examples compile successfully on clang (that declares constexpr lambda support that is -- 8.0.0) the following snippet doesn't and I can't imagine why... Any ideas?

```
template <int>
struct Foo {};

int main() {
    constexpr int c = 1;
    auto lambda = []{return (c, 2);};
    static_cast<void>(Foo<lambda()>{});
}
```

Compilation error:

> variable 'c' cannot be implicitly captured in a lambda with no capture-default specified

[[live demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VrC6qZ2nPiCYaknN)

Comment: not an answer but... in wandbox clang++ complain because "variable 'c' cannot be implicitly captured in a lambda with no capture-default specified"; capturing by reference (`[&]`) complain because "reference to 'c' is not a constant expression"; capturing by value (`[=]`) compile without problems. The funny part is that g++ compile in all three cases without problem.

Comment: I think comma operator takes a reference to c, and references break constexpr

Comment: @max66 huh! haven't tested it with `[=]` this makes things look more as a clang bug, no?

Comment: I don't think is a comma problem: I get the same with `auto lambda = []{ c; return 2;};`

Comment: @max66 ugh so we aren't in place where clang fully supports constexpr lambda yet...?

Comment: @Dani do you think it's legit?

Comment: clang bug? I'm not a language layer so, frankly, I don't know.

Comment: But works perfectly `constexpr auto lambda = []{ auto a=c; return a;};`; so no problem with `c` value but error when `c` is seen as reference to `c`?

Comment: Exactly, I find this very suspicious...

Comment: Just log a bug at bugs.llvm.org for it being different, the one answer seems to indicate that GCC is right

Comment: @JVApen it doesn't happen cery often :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its seems to be a clang bug, according to [[basic.def.odr]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#4):

> A variable x whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression ex is odr-used by ex unless applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (7.1) to x yields a constant expression (8.20) that does not invoke any non-trivial functions and, if x is an object, ex is an element of the set of potential results of an expression e, where either the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (7.1) is applied to e, **or e is a discarded-value expression**.

As has been commented, the issue is not limited to the comma operator but for every discarded expressions, these expression doesn't constitute *odr-use*, hence it must be accepted.

Answer (score 3):

This is a clang bug, if we look at a simpler case:

```
constexpr int c = 1;
auto lambda =  [] {return c,2;};
```

clang also considers this ill-formed ([see it live](https://godbolt.org/z/RjqbQe)), the lambda is required to capture an automatic variable if it odr-uses it see [expr.prim.lambda.capturep8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.prim.lambda.capture#8):

> An entity is captured if it is captured explicitly or implicitly. An entity captured by a lambda-expression is odr-used in the scope containing the lambda-expression. If *this is captured by a local lambda expression, its nearest enclosing function shall be a non-static member function. If a lambda-expression or an instantiation of the function call operator template of a generic lambda **odr-uses this or a variable with automatic storage duration from its reaching scope, that entity shall be captured by the lambda-expression**. If a lambda-expression captures an entity and that entity is not defined or captured in the immediately enclosing lambda expression or function, the program is ill-formed.  ...

and [discarded value expression is not an odr-use](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition).

I found a similar [bug report  [rejects valid] constexpr non-scalar variable not usable in lambda without capture or local class](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35255).

Comment: Wow I was sure I tested it without calling lambda too, but appearantly I missed that... So you are probably right that the problem runs deeper...